# how to validate map is null or not in generic

Tags: java, collections

I need to validate a Map value is null or not,since I  work offen with collections,willing to implement generic way of validating the map value,so tried this

```
public boolean checkNull(Map<String,Object> data){

        if(data != null && !data.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

now I can able to validate my map only with key as string and value as object,but I also need to check this null condition with any type of map Map or Map.etc,
so how can I do a generic function to validate this map process.

```
  public boolean checkNull(Map<K,V> data){

            if(data != null && !data.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

will some one can help me to understand this logic in deep.

Comment: No need for having a generic method as you do not need the key or value type in the method implementation. Just use `Map<?, ?>` as the input argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public boolean checkNull(Map<String,?> data){

       // and you can also use this instead of the if:
       return data != null && !data.isEmpty();
    }
```

or

```
 public boolean checkNull(Map<?,?> data){
```

depending on what is known or should be checked by the compiler.

Comment: This restricts the map having `String` typed keys, although the method does not use that restriction. `Map<?, ?>` would be much better.

Comment: @laune Thanks for the answer but I am willing to know whats the "?" actually mean?.how its validate internally whether it will consider it as Object

Comment: It means that you don't know anything about the type except "Object or a sublass of Object". You can also specify that the type is from a subset of the type hierarchy: `? extends Foo` = a Foo or any subclass thereof.

Comment: @Kao It was not mine to begin with, but OK, fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Map<K,V> data` to `Map<?, ?> data`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public <K, V> boolean checkNull(Map<K, V> entry){
    if(entry!=null&&!entry.isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then call `<String, Integer> checkNull(myStringAndIntegerMapInstance)` which ensure also type reference issues at runtime. See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) for more.